# is there a pre-compiled OAuth frameworks for objective c that i can download?

Tags: iphone, frameworks, sdk, oauth

i cant compile it for some reason...

Comment: maybe we can also help with "some reason" if you have an actual error message.

Comment: problem with compiling was the "Compile and build" button was disabled. therefore: no error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://github.com/bengottlieb/Twitter-OAuth-iPhone